# Automatically produce summary by factor variable in R

Tags: r

I've got a dataframe like the following:

```
   case simulation temp plank oxygen
1     1          1    8     7     11
2     2          1   16    10     15
...
17   17          2   26    12     17
18   18          2   15     8     12
19   19          2   28    11     21
20   20          2   24     6     14
```

I'd like to get summaries split by the levels of the simulation variable. For example, I'd like the mean of `temp` for simulation==1 and simulation==2, and the same for standard deviation.

At the moment I'm using the following code, which is pretty horrible:

```
df <- read.csv("data.csv")
attach(df)

# Create subset variables
temp1 = subset(temp, simulation==1)
temp2 = subset(temp, simulation==2)

plank1 = subset(plank, simulation==1)
plank2 = subset(plank, simulation==2)

oxygen1 = subset(oxygen, simulation==1)
oxygen2 = subset(oxygen, simulation==2)

print(sd(temp1))
print(sd(temp2))
print(sd(plank1))
print(sd(plank2))
```

I'm sure there must be an automatic way to do this in R, but I can't find it. I've tried using `summary(df ~ simulation)`, but that doesn't produce anything useful.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check out the `by()` or `tapply()` functions. Basically,

```
tapply(y, g, mean)
```

will give you the mean of `y` by levels of `g`. If you want to get a data.frame from the resulting aggregated measures, use `aggregate()`.

A more elaborated solution is available through the `summary.formula()` function in the [Hmisc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/index.html) package.

Answer (score 3):

package `doBy` has a `summaryBy` function that has a formula based syntax like the one you tried.

Also, i think that question would have been better asked on stackexchange.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look at the package. This is stackexchange isn't it?

Comment: I think fabians meant Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com which is for R programming, how do I do something in R questions. This place is more generally about stats. The two can blend a lot, however.